# Sorting list of URLs by length in Jython

Tags: url, list, sorting, jython

I am writing a Jython script to sort a list of URLs.

I have a list that looks like this:

http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/|,1
http://www.domain.com/folder1/|,1
http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/|,1
http://www.domain.com/folder1/|,1
http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/|,1
http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/|,1
http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/|,1

The pipe and the comma separates the path from the amount of files that are under that path.
Is it possible some how use Jython to order the URLs by length, so it would end up look like the below list:

http://www.domain.com/folder1/|,1
http://www.domain.com/folder1/|,1
http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/|,1
http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/|,1
http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/|,1
http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/|,1
http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/|,1

Hope you guys get what I mean, any help would be appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort-by-length, using a sort function:

```
urls.sort(lambda a, b: cmp(len(a), len(b)))
```

For performance, some might prefer the decorate-sort-undecorate pattern:

```
urllengths= [(len(url), url) for url in urls]
urllengths.sort()
urls= [url for (l, url) in urllengths]
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
urls= zip(*sorted((len(url), url) for url in urls))[1]
```

Comment: jython supports a `key` argument for `sort()`, so you could just use: `urls.sort(key=len)`.

Comment: only supported since jython-2.5 not on the 2.2 series

Answer (score 1):

Until jython catches up to *python 2.4*, you cannot use the *key* argument to *list.sort()*:

```
mylist.sort(key=len)
```

So, like in the good old days, we have the [decorate-sort-undecorate](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52234/) idiom. To sort `mylist` by item length, we generate a `decorated_list` of `(len(item),item)` tuples, sort that, and finally strip the items back:

```
decorated_list = zip(map(len, mylist), mylist)
decorated_list.sort()
sorted_list = [i[1] for i in decorated_list]
```

Comment: For the symmetry I would use: `sorted_list = map(operator.itemgetter(1), decorated_list)` instead of `sorted_list = [i[1] for i in decorated_list]`

Comment: Or (for symmetry):
  decorated_list = zip([len(i) for i in mylist], mylist)
(Jython 2.2)

Comment: Jython 2.2 doesn't have operator.itemgetter().

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't sorting them take care of this?

Comment: The English dictionary is sorted, but you don't get all the 1-letter words before all the 2-letter words